# How to show user's name based on user_id of a blog post on laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, one-to-many

I am trying to show the user name based on the **user_id** column of the post on the view.

But I keep getting this error:  `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::belonsTo()`

Here is my Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
  public function user()
    {
      return $this->belonsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

My User model:

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

My Pages Controller based on [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

```
use App\User;
use App\Post;
    class PagesController extends Controller {
        public function getIndex() {
            $post = Post::find(1);
            echo $post->user->name;
        return view('pages.welcome')->withPost($post);
    }
```

Comment: "belonsTo"...? Belongs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write `belonsTo` but is `belongsTo` :)

Comment: I don't know what to say :) For 2 hours I couldn't see this. Thank you!